# Github organization invite v.s. request membership

Tags: github

I am making a small Git / Github demo for first-time users and want to use Github Pages, for which I needed to create a new Github organization. During the 30 min I'll have to do the demo, users will need to create new Github accounts and join the organization. Since I'll have so little time, is it possible for users to *request* organization membership, rather than me having to *invite* each person manually by email lookup?

I've seen this before but only through third-party apps. Is there no way to do this directly within Github?

Comment: Maybe https://education.github.com/ has something you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly with GitHub, I have seen no evidence of that feature.

Through third-party apps indeed, yes.
As an example: [`benbalter/add-to-org`](https://github.com/benbalter/add-to-org) would  automatically add users to an organization.

Comment: Thank you, looks like I'll have to go through a third party. I'll look into your example!

Answer (score 0):

For smaller teams, this may not be possible. The feature that you have mentioned seems similar to user provisioning and is available for Enterprises through Okta /Azure Active Directory. This link has more details on the [User Provisioning](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/admin/identity-and-access-management/managing-iam-with-enterprise-managed-users/configuring-scim-provisioning-for-enterprise-managed-users).